# Keypad Control Problems

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, gpio

So for my final project in AP Comp Sci I decided to build a Pi and Arduino robot, since I'm going to use the Pi to control the Arduino through it's digital inputs (the Arduino's that is), I wanted to create and test my keypad control, so I breadboarded some LEDs to a GPIO and wrote this code:

```
import pygame
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
pygame.init()
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(32,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(36,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(40,GPIO.OUT)

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

pygame.display.set_caption("Console")

def clearGP():
        x=32
        while x<=40 :
          GPIO.output(x,False)
          x= x+4

run = True



while run :
  for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):
                 keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                 if keys[pygame.K_s] and keys[pygame.K_a]:
                        GPIO.output(40,True)
                        GPIO.output(32,True)

                 elif keys[pygame.K_s] and keys[pygame.K_d]:
                        GPIO.output(40,True)
                        GPIO.output(36,True)

                 elif keys[pygame.K_w]:
                    GPIO.output(32,True)
                    GPIO.output(36,True)

                 elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
                    GPIO.output(40,True)

                 elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
                    GPIO.output(36,True)

                 elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
                    GPIO.output(32,True)

                 elif keys[pygame.K_t]:
                    run=False

                 clearGP()


GPIO.cleanup()
pygame.quit()
```

However, when it was supposed to output to two lights at once *for example when a & s are pressed* (in my test circuit) it only output to one! Also, the light was blinking, really fast, not slow, I want it to stay solid as long as I'm holding down the key, as I want my bot to be consistent rather than jittery (in terms of mobility). What do I do?

P.S. I know I used Pygame, this is not for a game. I just thought that it's key tracking was easier to use than Tkinter as I have little Python experience (I'm really a Java guy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, because you're running this on the 'KEYDOWN' event, it will run as soon as it detects the first of the two keys you pressed even if you think you pressed them simultaneously. So by the time you get to get key.get_pressed() only one of the buttons is pressed.

Try removing both of these lines (and re-indenting) and see if it works better:

`for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):`

It's blinking because you're calling clearGP() on every cycle, so you will light the LED for 50% of a cycle and turn it off for the other 50%.  You should turn the LEDs off only if the key is not pressed e.g.

```
if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                GPIO.output(32,True)
else:
                GPIO.output(32,False)
```

Comment: I'll try this and let you know how it goes